# What is the name of this red and blue striped spider (?) - Brazil, Rio de Janeiro

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology, arachnology

[image: Colorful small spider(?) from Rio de Janeiro, Brazil]

Anyone knows the name of this thing? I found it in our bathroom. It is maybe 10-15 mm.

It looks like a spider but the colors left me puzzled

Comment: Definitely a spider (fused head+thorax, eight legs, jaws) but sheesh those colours :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This appears to be some species of jumping spider (family [Salticidae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jumping_spider)) in the genus [***Psecas***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psecas).

For example, some red/blue striped species of *Psecas*:

[image: psecas 1]]
[image: http://tolweb.org/tree/ToLimages/psecas.gif]

<sup>Sources: Top: [Alchetron.com](https://alchetron.com/Psecas) (image: [Edwards, 2001](https://alchetron.com/cdn/psecas-507f5c14-a3d0-48ad-ae10-5549f1f244b-resize-750.jpg))  |   Bottom: [Tree of Life](http://tolweb.org/onlinecontributors/app;jsessionid=A1F7A6DABC8CB7848838B1A26F70E740?page=ViewImageData&service=external&sp=2403) (image: Maddison 1994)</sup>

Wikipedia lists the following species from Brazil:

- *Psecas chapoda* (Peckham & Peckham, 1894) – Brazil
- *Psecas chrysogrammus* (Simon, 1901) – Peru, Brazil
- *Psecas viridipurpureus* (Simon, 1901) – Brazil
- *Psecas zonatus* (Galiano, 1963) – Brazil

***Psecas chrysogrammus* is my best guess** given my limited knowledge of the specimen, this family, and arachnid literature.

We likely can rule out *P. viridipurpureus* (see [here](https://www.whatsthatbug.com/category/spiders/jumping-spiders/page/12/)) and *P. chapoda* (see [here](http://salticidae.org/salticid/diagnost/psecas/chapoda.htm)) because of the longitudinal striping pattern of the dorsal abdomen of these two species.

I couldn't find any definitive or reputable sources regarding *P. zonatus*.

The sketch of *P. chrysogrammus* [here](http://salticidae.org/salticid/diagnost/psecas/chrysogr.htm) seems to indicate that this specific species has the horizontal striping seen in the OP's specimen.

[Salticidae.org](http://salticidae.org/salticid/diagnost/psecas/chrysogr.htm) provides these sources for *P. chrysogrammus* ID info:

- M. E. Galiano 1963b. Las especies americanas de aranas de la familia Salticidae, descriptas por Eugene Simon. Redescripciones basadas en los ejemplares tipicos. Physis, Buenos Aires, 23 (66): 424, t. 32, f 14-18.
- Simon E. 1901a. Histoire Naturelle des Araignees. 2(3-4) Paris: 460, f 528, 533(=H).