# What type of insect or bee is this?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

First time with Mason Bees here in Tacoma WA. We had three come out of their cocoons today. One female is working in a tube. But we had one insect who flew up to near the bee house, shook off their wings and is now wandering all over the bee house.

Is this a mason bee or something else? Should I be concerned?

[image: Unidentified Insect]

Comment: What is the approximate size of your specimen? Please update your post using the [edit] button to include at least an approximate size. Thanks. See [here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/tags/species-identification/info) for how to write a well-received [tag:species-identification] question that has a better chance of getting a good (and correct) answer.

Answer (score -1):

[Black garden ant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_garden_ant#Mating_flights) and associated image from its Wikipedia page.

[image: black garden ant (Lasius niger), also known as the common black ant]

Ants and bees [don't get along](https://www.flickr.com/photos/sam2cents/513631926) so if you want the bees you should get rid of the ants.

Comment: I've downvoted b/c many ants look similar, & your post hasn't done anything to convince readers this is an accurate ID. It appears as a guess w/ a picture. You should indicate explicitly what characteristics of *L. niger* you find to match the OP's specimen. You could also address why it's *not* other related or similar looking species. Finally, please examine & mention the likelihood of your answer based on known range info...For example, the range map for *L. niger* from [antsmap.org](http://antmaps.org/?mode=species&species=Lasius.niger) suggests it's an exotic with few records in WA...

Comment: @theforestecologist Thank you for the guidance, I should wait until it is "[well asked](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)".

Comment: Rob, I agree -- getting more info from a better asked question is ideal. In the absence of an update to the question, I recommend 1 of two things: 1. just move on. or 2. Write a darn good, detailed answer being very clear about *why* you think it is what it is. Even if you're not correct, your reasoning will be valuable and might encourage discussion, question edits, or additional answers. You could also present various species options and "teach" us why it's unclear which is correct and which characteristic to look out for and how specific traits would be indicative of specific species.

Comment: For example, see my [answer](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/79050/16866) to  [this post](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/79038/16866). I wasn't sure of the answer, but I present the likely group and try to narrow based on characteristics and ranges.

Comment: @theforestecologist The cephalothorax of blackjack75's spider looks different than your two examples, but I may have [found you a better photo](https://www.whatsthatbug.com/category/spiders/page/22/), a 'my guess is better than your guess' discussion isn't productive unless one of us is a myrmecologist. What ***is*** really helpful, is [this Meta post of yours](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3680/species-identification-tag-warning-proposal), a comment from the Moderator might assist Susan and be better received than a random person's comment (mine). Thanks again. Moving on.

Comment: @theforestecologist - Perhaps "I found a bug" questions should go to our [The Great Outdoors](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/21867/what-type-of-insect-is-this-orange-camouflaged-creature) site. More upvotes per effort expended.

Comment: I'd rather they stay here where both the question and the answer will be held to higher standards and therefore likely result in a more accurate (vs *seemingly* close-enough) learning moment for the OP and future visitors. You can see a previous issue I had concerning the robustness/accuracy of effort taken by previous TGO ID posts [here](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/a/19595/6401)

Comment: I'm all for correctness and accuracy, but the last couple of askers haven't been interested in providing a *better* question they don't want TMI, only JEI (just enough info). I agree, this being the biology site, that a high standard ought to be adhered to; the ***question*** is, what kind of answer do they need/want (much as on Physics, Stats, Math, etc.SE). A simple "I found a bug" question might only want a "it looks like this" answer. While the [other asker](https://biology.stackexchange.com/users/35897/user35897) has earned a few points they filled out their profile: "In 9th grade".