# What is this spider with blue striped head?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, arachnology

[image: blue striped spider]

I found this spider on the balcony of a Brisbane, Australia quarantine hotel. About 1.5cm. Anyone know what it is?

Comment: Colourful find, it's not among the [common listed types](https://www.brisbaneinsects.com/brisbane_spiders/SpidersFieldGuide.htm), or the common poisonous ones. Best to be careful and not handle until identified. Please take our [tour] and refer to the [help] for guidance.  Also, take a read of our [species ID guidelines](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3453/5509) and see what you can add that might help.

Comment: +1 for excellent photo

Comment: Related: https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/79038/what-is-the-name-of-this-red-and-blue-striped-spider-brazil-rio-de-janeir

Comment: I knew Australia was taking COVID seriously, but to quarantine the spiders too is quite impressive.

Comment: @BruceWayne Perhaps the spider isn't quarantined; perhaps it's a guard to prevent the "guests" from escaping ;)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I was simply writing this as a comment, but it became too long/detailed. I wanted to supplement @timeskull's [answer](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/105540) with a bit more nuance.

I agree that this looks like a *female* [***Cosmophasis micarioides***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmophasis_micarioides)

A more similar looking specimen to the OP's photo:

[image]

<sup>Credit: Tony Bailey , Source: [findaspider.org](http://www.findaspider.org.au/find/spiders/494.htm)</sup>

You can read more about the species [here](http://www.arachne.org.au/01_cms/details.asp?ID=2583), including that its "extremely variable." Importantly, the mature male is much darker with blue and black lines, while the female is much brighter with reds/yellows. Sub-adult males actually look like a cross between the two:

> The female can feature combinations of orange, black, red or blue-green, usually with metallic bands across the cephalothorax. The males look like females until they become sub adult, when they look like a cross between the female and the adult male...You can recognise C. micarioides males by their black face lines

@timeskull's [answer](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/105540) looks different from the OP's specimen because the specimens in that photo are likely sub-adult males or juveniles vs. females. -- they're actually identified as juveniles [here](http://www.arachne.org.au/01_cms/details.asp?ID=2583)

According to [Whyte & Anderson (2017)](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/329139666_A_Field_Guide_to_Spiders_of_Australia)<sup>1</sup>, the species is widespread and common in tropical Australia south **to Brisbane**.

---

<sup>1. Whyte, Robert; Anderson, Greg (2017). A Field Guide to Spiders of Australia. Clayton South Vic. 3169: CSIRO publishing. p. 236. ISBN 9780643107076</sup>

Comment: "Toxicity: May cause local inflammation". - "The jumping spiders are not toxic except for the [Mopsus mormon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mopsus_mormon)."

Comment: Looks like we have another "What color is the dress?" meme candidate - the blue in the original image is likely due to the reflected light appearing that color from certain angles...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman right you are. The name *micarioides* actually refers to the "micaceus" (mica-like) body scales that reflect different colors when viewed from different angles.

Answer (score 15):

It's a female Cosmophasis micarioides.

It's obviously a salticid, so I looked through the [thumbnails of jumping spiders](http://www.arachne.org.au/01_cms/details.asp?ID=1096) at arachne.org.au until I saw the green and orange head bands. Fortunately they used the female spider for the thumbnail as the male looks quite different and I wouldn't have checked if it was pictured.
[image: photo by Dr Greg Anderson]
Description and more images on the species page:
http://www.arachne.org.au/01_cms/details.asp?ID=2583

Comment: Good find. Colorful like a jumping spider, but the eyes weren't clear in the OP's photo.